# Django: Cannot login to Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I tried to login to Django Admin. However I get this error:

```
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'auth_user'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Before this, I have no problem login to Django Admin after migrated `auth_user` to MSSQL database. I could not figure out why is this happen and how to fix it?

This is the log

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mssql\base.py", line 576, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'auth_user'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 472, in thread_handler
        raise exc_info[1]
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
        response = await get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 253, in _get_response_async
        response = await wrapped_callback(
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 435, in __call__
        ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 408, in wait_for
        return await fut
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 476, in thread_handler
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 441, in login
        return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 92, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
        return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 90, in dispatch
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 152, in post
        if form.is_valid():
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
        self.full_clean()
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 438, in full_clean
        self._clean_form()
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 459, in _clean_form
        cleaned_data = self.clean()
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 217, in clean
        self.user_cache = authenticate(
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 42, in sensitive_variables_wrapper
        return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 77, in authenticate
        user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 46, in authenticate
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 46, in get_by_natural_key
        return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 646, in get
        num = len(clone)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in __len__
        self._fetch_all()
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1866, in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 87, in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql(
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1398, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:\Users\ALMA1210857\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mssql\base.py", line 576, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'auth_user'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

Comment: Did you migrate auth_user successfully? What was the logs?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: Besides login into Django admin, what else functions are not working? such as accessing User objects.

Comment: Yes. I also cannot do authentication for User.

Comment: Before migrated `auth_user `, what changes you did? Such as modified User field. May I see the git diff before/after migrated `auth_user `?

Comment: add **database** setting

Comment: If you git check out to previous version, will this issue still exist?